# How do I use two different flash to js movies on same page?

Tags: javascript

How do I change the js to be able to view two different flash movies that I have created in "Create js toolkit"? Only one of the movies show. I know I need to change the code but I dont know how.
Please help!
Kindly Eva.

This is the code for my site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Modedrive-Från vardag till fest-för kvinnor i alla åldrar</title>
<link href="Styles/Modedrive_cs5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Julfilm.js"></script>
<script src="Modedrive-film7.js"></script>

 <script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    images = images||{};

    var manifest = [
        {src:"images/_2013.png", id:"_2013"},
        {src:"images/Godjul.png", id:"Godjul"},
        {src:"images/Gottnytt.jpg", id:"Gottnytt"},
        {src:"images/Julkulor.png", id:"Julkulor"},
        {src:"images/Julkulor2.png", id:"Julkulor2"},
        {src:"images/Vivillonska.png", id:"Vivillonska"}
    ];

    var loader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
    loader.onFileLoad = handleFileLoad;
    loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
    loader.loadManifest(manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(o) {
    if (o.type == "image") { images[o.id] = o.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.Julfilm();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage);
}
</script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    images = images||{};

    var manifest = [
        {src:"images/Bettykofta.jpg", id:"Bettykofta"},
        {src:"images/Byxdress.jpg", id:"Byxdress"},
        {src:"images/Fur.jpg", id:"Fur"},
        {src:"images/Kofta.jpg", id:"Kofta"},
        {src:"images/leopkavajred.jpg", id:"leopkavajred"},
        {src:"images/Leopardjacka.jpg", id:"Leopardjacka"},
        {src:"images/liladress.jpg", id:"liladress"},
        {src:"images/Longdress.jpg", id:"Longdress"},
        {src:"images/Redzebrakofta.jpg", id:"Redzebrakofta"},
        {src:"images/Skinnjacka.jpg", id:"Skinnjacka"},
        {src:"images/vitsvponcho.jpg", id:"vitsvponcho"}
    ];

    var loader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
    loader.onFileLoad = handleFileLoad;
    loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
    loader.loadManifest(manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(o) {
    if (o.type == "image") { images[o.id] = o.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.Modedrivefilm7();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/mode_bakg.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">

 <div id="container">
  <div id="logo"><img src="images/Modedrive-logo.png" width="900" height="163" alt="Modedrive" />
  <p>Fr&aring;n vardag till fest f&ouml;r kvinnor i alla &aring;ldrar.</p></div>
  <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Hem</a>    </li>
    <li><a href="historik.html">Historik</a></li>
    <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="designs.html">M&auml;rken</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="designs.html">V&aring;ra M&auml;rken</a></li>
        <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="http://www.tee4twogolf.se">Vi st&ouml;djer</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.tee4twogolf.se">Tee 4 Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="team_tiara.html">Team Tiara</a></li>
            <li><a href="xocai.html">Xo&ccedil;ai</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="aktuellt.html">Aktuellt</a></li>
    <li><a href="VIP.html">VIP Kundklubb</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakta oss</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="main">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="775" height="270" style="background-color:#000000"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div id="left_column"><h1>440 m&#178 med mode!</h1><p>Vi hj&auml;lper dig<br /> hitta r&auml;tt<br />bland s&auml;songens<br /> modenyheter<br />f&ouml;r kvinnor<br /> i alla &aring;ldrar<br />fr&aring;n vardag<br /> till fest.</p><h2>V&auml;lkommen in!</h2></div>

  <div id="center_column">
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="420" height="570" style="background-color:#000000"></canvas>

  </div>
  <div id="right_column"><h1>Just nu...</h1>
  <p><h1>K&ouml;p tv&aring;<br /> plagg</h1><h2>betala</h2><h1> 1 krona</h1><h2>f&ouml;r det billigaste!<br /><br />Nu har vi <br />advents&ouml;ppet<br />p&aring; s&ouml;ndagar mellan<br />12-16:00 </h2>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"><p><img src="images/Tbana-liten.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Tbana symbol" />Odenplan, Karlbergsv&auml;gen 16, 11327 Stockholm. Tel: o8-343838<br />&Ouml;ppet tider: Vardagar 10-19:00, L&ouml;rdagar 10-16:00, S&ouml;ndagar 12-16:00.</p></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```